# System V Semaphore usage in PHP

Tags: php, concurrency, semaphore

my answer is quite simple:
is it possible to use a system_v semaphore in PHP to solve producer-consumer problem?
I mean, classical prod-cons solution can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem).

```
semaphore fillCount = 0; // items produced
semaphore emptyCount = BUFFER_SIZE; // remaining space

procedure producer() {
    while (true) {
        item = produceItem();
        down(emptyCount);
            putItemIntoBuffer(item);
        up(fillCount);
    }
}

procedure consumer() {
    while (true) {
        down(fillCount);
            item = removeItemFromBuffer();
        up(emptyCount);
        consumeItem(item);
    }
}
```

As you can see a producer increment the `fillCount` after putting an item in the buffer.
Anyway, as I understood in the php-doc you can only use sem_acquire and sem_release to manipulate semaphore and you cannot call sem_release without having acquired it before.
Do you have any idea of how to workaround this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's important, consider using a real message queue server: RabbitMQ, OpenAMQ, ActiveMQ, ZeroMQ, beanstalkd, *etc*. Using semaphores or other local mechanisms won't scale beyond a single server.

Comment: of course...you're right. It was just intended for accademic purpose :D

Comment: anyway, it's the first time I read of RabbitMQ (i've previously read of NodeJS, Ajax Push Engine and so on), but none of them seems that good! =)